# how to get data from custom table

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get all value of Custom table with image

Table name : `imguplaod` column name : `img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all data with below query

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('imguplaod'=>'imguplaod'));

$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);

foreach($alldata as $img)
   {
     echo $img['img'];
   }
```

Comment: I tried this but i want all images in that table

Comment: this will get all record from databse

Comment: Yes i understand but i want img column and with image in frontend i need to display

Comment: updated the code...............

Comment: No luck not dispaly

Comment: updated code try and feedback